# php preg_replace question.. how to get rid of a space?

Tags: php

```
$thisdate = '2011-01-18 14:52:33';

$security = preg_replace('/[^\d\s]/', '', $thisdate);

echo $security;
```

This results in 20110118 145233

How would i get rid of the space?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your regex matches everything that is not(`^`) digit(`\d`) or space(`\s`)

so if you remove the `\s`

```
preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $thisdate);
```

will replace everything except digits

Answer (score 1):

take the `\s` out of the regex

Answer (score 0):

While changing the regex is definitely the superior answer...

[`str_replace`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) can also work.

```
$security = str_replace($security, '\s', '');
```